# Will a Firestore snapshot listener return with pending writes ever fail to make those writes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Will a Firestore snapshot listener return with pending writes ever fail to make those writes? I want to know if I can safely ignore latency compensation returns when I make local changes to data so that I don't handle them twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore writes don't fail until the server tells you they fail.  If it does fail, the reason will usually be due to a security rule violation, or exceeding some rate limit.  A complete list of errors (Android) can be found in the [API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code).

Without an explicit failure, the client SDK will continue to attempt the write until it hears something back from the server.

Comment: If the error is due to a security violation or rate-limit exception, the latency-compensated return still fires?

Comment: Yes, the initial event fires locally, before the server is contacted. If you want to be able to ignore the initial client-side event, be sure to [listen for metadata changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) too.